# Calculate the limit of integral sum

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

Find limit of $$a_n = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{k}}$$

My attempt is:

$$\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{n}} < \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{k}} < \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}$$

Note as  $n \to \infty \Rightarrow n + \frac{1}{n} \to n \Rightarrow \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{n}} \to \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}$.

Therefore, by squeeze theorem the limit of central sum is equal to the limit of lateral sums.

Then let's find limit when $n \to \infty$ of the following $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n} = 2^{\frac{1}{n}} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot2^k$.

Let's take $f(x) = 2^x$, the norm of partition is equal to $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, $\xi_k = \frac{k}{n}$, then $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot2^{\frac{k}{n}} \to \int \limits_0^1 2^x dx = \frac{2^x}{\ln 2}\Big|_0^{1} = \frac{1}{\ln2}$.

So, our initial sum has the following limit.

I have a few questions about my solution:

I'm pretty sure that my explanation of why $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{n}} \to \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n}$ is not strict enough. Can someone please explain this moment more carefully?

Is it true that $n + \frac{1}{n} \to n$?

In general, is the following is true: if $ f(x) \to g(x) \Rightarrow g(x) \to f(x)$.

Are there any other options to solve this particular problem using Riemann sum?

Comment: Good idea to use the squeeze theorem. Try the simpler estimation of the lateral sums: $\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{n} > a_n > \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1}$ These lateral sums can be calculated explicitly and their (coinciding) limits are $\frac{1}{\log 2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea of user23316192 to use the squeeze theorem.

We can improve his reasonings a little by simplifying the estimation of the lateral sums:

$$\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1} < a_n < \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{n} $$

The main part of these lateral sums is the geometric sum

$$\sum _{k=1}^n 2^{k/n}=\frac{2^{1/n}}{2^{1/n}-1}$$

The limit to be considered is (for $k = 0$ or $k = 1$)

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{2^{1/n}}{\left(2^{1/n}-1\right) (k+n)}=\frac{1}{\log (2)}$$

Main details are here the definition $2^x = e^{x \log 2}$ and the power series development $e^x \simeq 1 + x$ from which we find

$$\frac{2^{1/n}}{2^{1/n}-1}=\frac{1}{1-2^{-\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{\log (2)}{n}}}\simeq \frac{1}{1-\left(1-\frac{\log (2)}{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\frac{\log (2)}{n}}$$

hence finally

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, a_n =\frac{1}{\log (2)}$$

Comment: Can you please explain why $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{2^{1/n}}{\left(2^{1/n}-1\right) (k+n)}
$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\log2}$?

Comment: I have modified my answer to explain this.

Comment: You are using the fact that $e^x \approx 1+x$, but it is only true when $x \to 0$ or am I wrong here?

Comment: @user6323104 Yes, it is true for $x \to 0$. Here we have $x  = \frac{\log 2}{n}$ which goes to $0$ when $n\to \infty$.